# Apex Test Class for Removing Prior Values on a Trigger

Tags: code-coverage

I have an Apex Trigger that is used to set some values to 'Null' as part of an Approval Process.

The Trigger is shown below:

```java
trigger AccountRemovePriorValues on Account (before Insert, before Update) {

    for(Account AccApr : trigger.new){


        try{
            boolean isRemovePriorChanged = AccApr.Remove_Prior_Values__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(AccApr.id).Remove_Prior_Values__c;
            if(isRemovePriorChanged && AccApr.Remove_Prior_Values__c == TRUE) {

                AccApr.Bank_Name_Prior__c = NULL;
                AccApr.Bank_Account_Name_Prior__c =  NULL;
                AccApr.Bank_Account_Number_Prior__c = NULL;
                AccApr.Bank_Account_Ref_Prior__c = NULL;
                AccApr.Bank_IBAN_Number_Prior__c = NULL;
                AccApr.Bank_Sort_Code_Prior__c = NULL;
                AccApr.Bank_SWIFT_Number_Prior__c = NULL;

                AccApr.Remove_Prior_Values__c = false;
            }
       }catch(System.NullPointerException e){Return;}
    }
}
```

Being new to Apex coding I was happy to get this working. The next challenge was writing a Test Method for this.

I wrote the below Test expecting it to be relatively simple. Now, I am getting 38% code coverage but not in the places I was expecting, ha! Particularly it doesn't seem to be querying the Null values. Could anyone offer any insight as to what I may be missing here? It will be super obvious to those of you on these forums but as a relative noob I'm lost. Any help would, as ever, be appreciated!

```java
@istest
private class AccountRemovePriorValues_Test {

    static testmethod void AccountRemovePriorValues() {

       Account AccApr = new Account(Remove_Prior_Values__c = TRUE,
       Name = 'Test Account Name',
       Bank_Name_Prior__c = Null,
       Bank_Account_Name_Prior__c =  Null,
       Bank_Account_Number_Prior__c = Null,
       Bank_Account_Ref_Prior__c = Null,
       Bank_IBAN_Number_Prior__c = Null,
       Bank_Sort_Code_Prior__c = Null,
       Bank_SWIFT_Number_Prior__c = Null);

       insert AccApr;

       AccApr = [SELECT Id, Name, Bank_Account_Name_Prior__c, Bank_Account_Number_Prior__c, Bank_Account_Ref_Prior__c, Bank_Name_Prior__c, Bank_IBAN_Number_Prior__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :AccApr.Id];

        System.assertEquals(NULL, AccApr.Bank_Name_Prior__c);

        update AccApr;     

    }

}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but (1) you can rely on objects provided by the trigger to not be `null`; and (2) `try/catch` blocks that don't meaningfully handle errors are a bad practice that will make your debugging life way harder.

Comment: According to your trigger, you have to insert the record with `Remove_Prior_Values__c=false` and then update the record with `Remove_Prior_Values__c = true`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have a couple of minor issues here.

First, the use of `Trigger.oldMap`. `Trigger.old` and `Trigger.oldMap` are not available in a `before insert` trigger context (which makes sense, because if you're inserting a completely new record, there are no old values as the record did not exist before now).

It's not an issue in your code, but it's also good to keep in mind that `trigger.newMap` is also not available `before insert`, because a new record being inserted is not assigned an Id until the `after insert` context.

I suspect this may be why you're using the try/catch to stifle the NPE. A much better approach would be to use some of the other trigger context variables that you have available (`Trigger.isBefore`, `Trigger.isInsert`, and `Trigger.isUpdate` will be helpful here).

An example of how to apply that to your trigger...

```java
trigger AccountRemovePriorValues on Account (before Insert, before Update) {
    for(Account AccApr : trigger.new){
        // This try/catch will become irrelevant
        //try{
            // Let's say that, by default, you want to remove prior values
            boolean isRemovePriorChanged = true;

            // If we're in a before update context, we want to double check to see if 
            //   we really should remove prior values
            // Checking isBefore isn't strictly necessary, since your trigger is currently
            //   only working on before events, but I find this to be good practice
            if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate){
                isRemovePriorChanged = AccApr.Remove_Prior_Values__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(AccApr.id).Remove_Prior_Values__c;
            }

            if(isRemovePriorChanged && AccApr.Remove_Prior_Values__c == TRUE) {

                AccApr.Bank_Name_Prior__c = NULL;
                AccApr.Bank_Account_Name_Prior__c =  NULL;
                AccApr.Bank_Account_Number_Prior__c = NULL;
                AccApr.Bank_Account_Ref_Prior__c = NULL;
                AccApr.Bank_IBAN_Number_Prior__c = NULL;
                AccApr.Bank_Sort_Code_Prior__c = NULL;
                AccApr.Bank_SWIFT_Number_Prior__c = NULL;

                AccApr.Remove_Prior_Values__c = false;
            }
       //}catch(System.NullPointerException e){Return;}
    }
}
```

The other trouble that I'm seeing is with your test method. You are setting all of the values that your trigger would set to null to `null` in your test, prior to running the trigger that you're trying to test.

That makes it quite hard to determine if your trigger ended up doing anything at all. It would be better if you set your fields (`Bank_Name_Prior__c`, `Bank_Account_Name_Prior__c`, `Bank_Account_Number_Prior__c`, etc...) to any other value (nonsense values are fine, so long as it complies with any validation rules you may have).

One last piece of advice, I would separate the test for the trigger when you insert a record from the test where you update a record. Having multiple test methods is good practice because it helps to keep each test small and focused (and then you only need to worry about setting up your test data for one situation)

Mangling tests together (that should logically be separated) is a recipe for (eventual) disaster. If you try to daisy-chain tests like that, you may find yourself eventually exhausting the governor limits. The bigger problem, however, is that you only have so much control over what gets executed as part of a test.

After running a test, the state of your test data is no longer "clean", and it can be hard to predict exactly what has been changed. A non-trivial part of unit testing is precisely controlling the inputs to each test. If you can't exactly specify your input, then you open yourself up to encountering strange "this should work, but why isn't it?" issues that can be hard to track down.

Answer (score 0):

If you check  the value of the variable `isRemovePriorChanged` It should be TRUE before the update as you stated on your test class. But if you want to enter `isRemovePriorChanged && AccApr.Remove_Prior_Values__c == TRUE` you have to update from FALSE to true, otherwise this  condition will be evaluated to false since the value of the vairbale `isRemovePriorChanged` is false.